Le Cam's two point method
I am looking for a source for Le Cam's two point method and I can't find any book that states in the form I could cite it. Specifically I am looking for the following result
$$
\sup_{\theta \in \Theta} \mathbb{E}_{P_\theta} \left[ L( \hat{\theta}(X), \theta ) \right] \geq \frac{\delta}{2} \left( 1 - \| P_0 - P_1 \|_{\text{TV}} \right)
$$
Thank you!

You can just cite Le Cam's original paper [1], although the paper is really on testing, not estimation and there isn't a precise statement of the form you want. What I've seen many people do (and have done myself), is to cite Le Cam, and then just provide a brief proof (since in the form written, this is a quick application of Neyman-Pearson).
Bin Yu's paper [2] gives more or less the form you want, and is often cited for this.
Books-wise, I think I've seen a statement of this form in Ingster-Suslina [3], but I don't have the book at hand. The cleanest statement (in that they don't worry about convexifying the lower bound and only operationalise it for functionals later) that I am aware of is in Ch. 31 of the book by Polyanksiy and Wu [4], although I believe this book isn't formally published yet.


LeCam, L. (1973). Convergence of estimates under dimensionality restrictions. The Annals of Statistics, 38-53.

Yu, B. (1997). Assouad, fano, and le cam. In Festschrift for Lucien Le Cam: research papers in probability and statistics (pp. 423-435). New York, NY: Springer New York.

https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-0-387-21580-8,

https://people.lids.mit.edu/yp/homepage/data/itbook-export.pdf and https://www.cambridge.org/highereducation/books/information-theory/CFF2F02ED54398148B7D8AA26E55B2BC#overview



Thank you! Can you share your paper on how to prove this inequality using Neyman-Paerson? Or a different paper that does this too?

I think Polyanskiy and Wu (and implicitly Yu) already do this, you can just look at that. The Neyman Pearson stuff is simply that if you have a test between two point hypotheses $P$ and $Q$, then for any test, the sum of the type 1 and 2 error rates exceeds $1 - \mathrm{TV}(P,Q)$ (this is really even weaker than N-P, but the point is that N-P says that for any type 1 error, there's an optimal test which is deterministic, which is enough for the statement to go through trivially).

Ok thanks. I am wondering though, because in Polyanskiy and Wu there is this $l(\theta_0,\theta_1)$ term on the right side which I don't have in the pape rI am reading. The result is in https://arxiv.org/pdf/2106.14866 on page 18 on the top. Any idea why that is? Sorry, I am new to this result sof statistcs and using it primarely to understand multi armed bandits.

$\ell$ is a loss function - you also have this in the inequality you wrote in the question. In the paper you linked, this appears to be $\ell(\mu, \mu') = |\mu-\mu'|$. Notice that this satisfies the standard triangle inequality (i.e., $\alpha = 1$). Presumably the paper chose a setup such that $|\mathbb{E}_0[\mu_i] - \mathbb{E}_1[\mu_i]| \ge \varepsilon,$ which is where the $\varepsilon$ in their RHS would come from.
